# Getx controller not found even after Get.put() | Flutter | Getx

Tags: flutter, dart, controller, flutter-getx

```
"YouController" not found. You need to call "Get.put(YouController())" or
"Get.lazyPut(()=>YouController())"
```

Getting this error even after I have Get.put() before coming to the screen.

Any Idea?

Comment: You need to include the whole code related to the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

create a file named `initial_bindings.dart` in your lib folder. Then add this snippet to it.

```js
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class InitialBinding implements Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut<YouController>(() => YouController(),fenix: true);
  }
}
```

Then in your `main.dart`, add this line into your `GetMaterialApp`.

```js
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      initialBinding: InitialBinding(), // add this line 
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Then whenever you want to access the controller, you can just use `Get.find<YourController>()` to use it.